# Objective C++ for loop multiple initialize fails

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I traced a bug in Objective C++ for iOS to this code

```
    for(int i = (maxBin - 4), max = 0; i <= (maxBin + 3); i++) {  
        max += (fftValLeft[i] * fftValLeft[i]);
    }
```

The "max = 0;" doesn't happen. I moved the initialization before the loop and all is good now.

This is with Xcode 4.6.3. Is this somehow normal C behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new variable called max whose scope is only visible to the for loop.
So once you come out of the loop, max value that you compute inside the loop is not visible outside of it.
Hope that helps.

Comment: The `-Wshadow` warning ("Hidden Local Variables") will catch this. It will complain that the `for` loop is declaring a new variable called `max` that shadows your existing variable.